# AS3-IntelliJ IDEA debugger: Unexpected debugged player communication problem

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, intellij-idea

For some reason I can't debug my actionscript application in IntelliJ. I keep getting this error in the console: Unexpected debugged player communication problem. I have no idea what causes this!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working. For some reason I don't understand, it worked when I installed Java JDK and downloaded a copy of msvcr71.dll to windows/system.

Wierd..

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the debugger version of the Flash Player, the one that has "Debugger" and "Show redraw regions" in the right-click menu, rather than the regular Flash Player?

http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

Comment: Yes, and thats the one that starts up if I choose run instead of debug. "You have version 10,0,45,2 installed". I'm supposed to have that for both ie and firefox as well as stand alone. And it's the one that starts up when I run it in flex builder instead.